# Does a projection decrease query and/or response time?

Tags: mongodb

I keep seeing the projection parameter in find() queries and was wondering if adding it makes things faster. I assume it does for large documents, but what about small documents of, say, 10 values or so?

I am seeking to optimize a project where MANY MANY small queries are performed.

Comment: It depends whether the query is covered or not

Comment: What have your tests shown? It's going to depend a lot on the queries and data, so the best way to answer this question is to try it on your systems with your data.

Comment: I am developing it now, but it will eventually have 4 million documents. Do you think I should generate those 4 mil collections and do tests on that? O_O

Comment: Yeah test with the 4 million. But the important things are indixes not projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should profile. In MongoDB shell, try `db.collection.find().explain()`.

If you have indexes, then it may help. Indexed queries are faster and if your queries only use fields stored in the index itself, you'll have a [covered query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#indexes-covered-queries) ([*indexOnly*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.indexOnly) in *cursor.explain()*). The *projection* parameter help to turn a query into a covered query.

If you insert documents more frequently than you read documents, then [it might not be a good idea to use indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#consider-insert-throughput), but you should always profile it.

Comment: ty for the complete, referenced answer.